# Error in xfun::normalize_path(path, ..., must_work = must_work, resolve_symlink = FALSE)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to run the file that comes by default from an Rmarkdown, however I get this error

[image: screenshot]

What I've tried so far:

1. Uninstall old versions of R;
2. Install version 4.2.3 of R and install Rstudio;
3. I thought it was a version problem and I installed 4.2.1 but the same error appears

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but perhaps the discussion [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/im-not-able-to-knit-after-i-install-new-version-of-r-rstudio-and-rtools/158029/6) has some relevance? The OP got a similar error message as you & was able to resolve it after updating the xfun package.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating yaml, markdown and rmarkdown. I tried updating xfun, but it kept loading version 0.34 even though 0.38 was available. I solved the problem by removing xfun first and then reinstalling it.

```
remove.packages('xfun')
install.packages('xfun')
```

Comment: same problem after installing pagedown.  If you end up here, heed the `remove.packages('xfun')`, as simply running the install portion didn't fix the problem (at least for me)